# Trigonometry value does not match reality

Tags: android, math, floating-point, trigonometry

I use `toRadians()` to convert value and find trigonometry such this

`dataMain = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(dataSub);`

but i have a problem such as `dataSub = 60`

Answer should be `0.5` 
but answer in my program is `0.50000000000001`

Or even `dataSub = 30`

`dataMain = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(dataSub);`

answer in my program is `0.49999999999994`

How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 5):

When you convert an angle from degrees to radians, the result is a number that is usually not exactly representable as a floating-point number. You only have about 16 digits to work with.

So, when you compute the cosine of `toRadians(60)`, you're actually calculating the cosine of a number very close to, but not equal to π/3.

How you want to fix this depends on your application. In the vast majority of real-world applications, a tiny inaccuracy such as this really doesn't make a difference. If you want to present the result nicely, then you can simply round to your desired number of digits.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some articles that will help you:

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

[Float](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/float.html)

Answer (score 0):

Fractions are stored as floating-point numbers, which are essentially an approximate value; this causes small inaccuracies such as the ones you've described. Wiser heads than mine have covered this at [sin, cos, tan and rounding error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527588/sin-cos-tan-and-rounding-error)

The best work-around is to round the value to an acceptable number of digits, and several methods are covered at [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

What Jeffrey said is absolutely correct, especially in this case. However, you might find similar results due to the following issue: often floats are represented internally using base 2. What this means is that your numbers are written as mantissa*2^(exponent). This is effectively taking your number and converting it to base 2, which is not always ideal. Say you want to represent 0.2 internally. The binary representation of 0.2 is not finite, it is in fact 0.00110011... (just as 1/3 is 0.3333... in base 10). Since you're only storing a finite number of digits for the mantissa, the number will get truncated when stored, and then when it gets converted back to decimal for printing it will show as 0.19999... instead of 0.2. I've noticed this a lot in python, for example. You can just type 0.2 in the interactive shell and it will spit out something close to 0.2 but slightly smaller or larger.